# Compare two columns with None's where None in one column is counted differently than the other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where I need to compare two columns that have `None` values. But I need to get a count of each of the combinations below.

```
|---------|---------|
|    A    |    B    |
|---------|---------|
|    1    |    1    |
|---------|---------|
|  None   |  None   |
|---------|---------|
|  None   |    1    |
|---------|---------|
|    1    |  None   |
|---------|---------|
|    1    |    2    |
|---------|---------|
```

Is there a better way to get the counts for the data with `None` values than code such as ?

```
len(df[(df["A"].isnull()) & ~(df["B"].isnull())])
```

I have also tried to use the groupby function but that also ignores None values.

Comment: It's not clear what you want, what do you mean with "count of each of the combinations".

Comment: Are you using Pandas? The standard for missing values in Pandas is `NaN`, not `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is use `notnull` function and then `sum` for count `True`s values:

```
a = (df["A"].isnull() & df["B"].notnull()).sum()
print (a)
1
```

Or in last versions of pandas are used similar functions:

```
a = (df["A"].isna() & df["B"].notna()).sum()
print (a)
1
```

Solution wiht removing `None`s by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
a = df.dropna(subset=['B'])['A'].isna().sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to solve this is by filling the empty values with 0.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, None, 2, None, 3], "B": [None, 2, 3, 4, None]})

     A    B
0  1.0   None
1  None  2.0
2  2.0   3.0
3  None  4.0
4  3.0   None

df = df.fillna(0)
df.sum()
```

The ouput is:

```
A    6.0
B    9.0
```